# What is the Unified Update Model?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

[This Clojure code](https://github.com/amalloy/useful/blob/develop/src/flatland/useful/fn.clj#L58) on GitHub refers to the Unified Update Model.

Could you explain how the `fixing` function works well with the Unified Update Model?

```
(defn fixing
  "A version of fix that fits better with the unified update model: instead of multiple clauses,
   additional args to the transform function are permitted. For example,
   (swap! my-atom fixing map? update-in [k] inc)"
  [x pred transform & args]
  (if ((as-fn pred) x)
    (apply (as-fn transform) x args)
    x))
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The unified update model is the API convention whereby objects of various reference types can be updated in a consistent way, albeit with specialized functions:

```
;; Atoms
(swap! the-atom f …)

;; Agents
(send the-agent f …)
(send-off the-agent f …)
;; send-via takes an additional initial argument, but otherwise
;; follows the same convention (and of course it's an exact match
;; when partially applied – (partial send-via some-executor))
(send-via executor the-agent f …)

;; Refs
(dosync
  (alter the-ref f …)
  (commute the-ref f…))
```

In each case `f` is the function that should be used to update the value held by the Atom / Agent / Ref, `…` are additional arguments, if any (e.g. `(swap! the-atom f 1 2 3)`), and the result of the call is that the reference will atomically assume the value `(f old-value …)` – although exactly when that will happen with respect to the `swap!` / `alter` / `send` / … call depends on the reference type in question and the update function used.

Here's an example:

```
(def a (atom 0))
(swap! a - 5)
@a
;= -5
```

Vars are generally not meant to be used for the same purposes that one might use the above-mentioned reference types for, but they also have an update function with the same contract:

```
(alter-var-root #'the-var f …)
```

Finally, the `update` and `update-in` functions are worth mentioning in this connection; in effect, they extend the unified update model convention to *values* – now of course, values are immutable, so calling `update` or `update-in` does not result in any object being visibly *changed*, but the return value is produced similarly as the result of applying an update function to a preexisting value and possibly some extra arguments:

```
(update {:foo 1} :foo inc)
;= {:foo 2}
```

The `fixing` function quoted in the question works better than `fix` (defined in the same namespace) in the context of UUM update calls, because it can be passed multiple arguments in a way that meshes well with how UUM update functions like `swap!` work, whereas with `fix` you'd have to use an anonymous function:

```
;; the example from the docstring of fixing
(swap! my-atom fixing map? update-in [k] inc)

;; modified to use fix
(swap! my-atom fix map? #(update-in % [k] inc))
```